# Copy constructor and a clone method in a Node class?

Tags: java, nodes, clone, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list

This is my first question on stackoverflow so if I didn't ask correctly please give me some insight on how to ask more appropriately.

I'm a bit confused on how to make a copy constructor and a clone method in a Node class. I understand how to make a copy and a clone (without implementing cloneable) for an object in general but I'm still new at LinkedLists.

Here's part of the code I have so far for the Node class (inner class of a LinkedList class)

```
private class Node
{
    private Foo fooObject;
    private Node link;

    public Node()
    {
        fooObject= null;
        link = null;
    }

    public Node(Foo fooObject, Node link )
    {
        this.fooObject = fooObject;
        this.setLink(link);
    }

    public Node(Node originalNode)
    {
        this(originalNode.getCourse(), originalNode.getLink());
    }

    public Node clone()
    {
        return new Node(this);
    }

    public Foo getFoo() 
    {
        return fooObject;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo fooObject) 
    {
        this.fooObject = fooObject;
    }

    public Node getLink() 
    {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Node link) 
    {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

Making a copy of a Node object still doesn't make much sense to me. Wouldn't this copy a node that is already linked to another node when you'd be using a Node object practically? The copy and the original would be linked to the same node, except the copy wouldn't have a node linking to it? Please help me understand in case I'm just confused, I don't understand how this would be used.

Just for clarification, the problem I'm trying to solve was asked at school in a lab. "Write a LinkedList class with an inner class... the inner class has a copy constructor and a clone method...make sure your copy constructor and clone method produce deep copies..."

*edit
Just want to clarify something, being asked to write a copy constructor and clone method in BOTH the LinkedList class and the inner Node class were asked. I'm 100% sure of this, I didn't have time to ask the TA for clarification because too many people were asking her questions!
*

Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain it says *the **inner** class has a copy constructor...*? I agree that doesn't make much sense but your implementation is correct.

Comment: Yeah I'm 100% sure, it asked to write the copy constructor and clone method for both the LinkedList class and the inner Node class. I was confused because I never saw that before but seeing as your the second person to try and clarify that, the TA or prof probably just made a mistake. I didn't get a chance to clarify with the TA during class time.
Thanks for replying quickly btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are being asked to implement the copy constructor and clone method on the Linked List class... not the Node class.

When specified to make a deep copy, your cloned Linked List object should copy all the nodes in the original Linked List.

I suggest you start with:

```
public MyLinkedList(MyLinkedList originalNode)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, 
I thought that as well, but the question asked during the lab specifically outlined that we had to write a copy constructor and a clone method in both the LinkedList class and the inner Node class. I was confused because I never saw that before, it's not even in my book. Could the TA or prof just have made a mistake? I didn't get a chance to clarify during class time because too many people were talking to the TA :/

Comment: Right, if they are asking you to make a copy / clone of the Node, then you use it as part of the deep copy process for the linked list. Immediately after making the Node copy, the Foo object will be correct but you'll need to update the link so it no longer points at a node in the original Linked List. Think of it as a convenience method to create your Linked List deep copy.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's where I'd change the link. Thanks for clarifying!